# Как просмотреть все значения атрибутов экземпляра класса в цикле?

Tags: python, методы, атрибуты

Нужно просмотреть все значения атрибутов экземпляра класса(File) в цикле. Собирался это сделать подобным образом:

```
file = File(path)
for atr in dir(file):
    if atr[:3] == '__' and atr[-2:] == '__':
        continue
    print(file.atr)
```

Но тщетно, так как у экземпляра нет атрибута atr. В atr при каждой итерации хранится название атрибута. Как можно, зная это название, вызвать данный метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `dir` для получения всех атрибутов.
И функцией `getattr` для получения их значений.

Пример вывода значений всех атрибутов экземпляра класса:

```py
class A():
    attr_1 = 'Spam!'
    attr_2 = 'Eggs'
    attr_3 = 'Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!'


x = A()
for attr in dir(x):
    if not attr.startswith('_'):  # Если не внутренний и не служебный
        print(getattr(x, attr))
```

***stdout:***

```html
Spam!
Eggs
Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!
```

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос - воспользуйтесь [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
print(getattr(file, atr))
```

если же `atr` является именем метода, а не атрибута, то данный метод можно вызвать так:

```
getattr(file, atr)(param1, param2, ...)
```

Comment: только не print а call, так как вызвать же надо.

Comment: @Ghostik2005 Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @nomnoms12 уже ничего :)

Answer (score 1):

В дополнении к `getattr` можно еще использовать `__dict__` объекта.

```
class Object():

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 1
        self.attr2 = 2
        self.attr3 = 3

obj = Object()

for key in obj.__dict__:
    print(obj.__dict__[key])

#Еще проще
print(obj.__dict__)
```